# Registration Link is not visible in My Account Page in Woocommerce ( Wordpress )

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, registration

I'm not able to register on My Account Page
I think internal Link is broken
Login Page is visible in My Account Page but no Registration Link is available 
I have marked the checkbox in Woocommerce Setting  Enable customer registration on the "My account" page.
Here is the code

```html
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

?>

<?php wc_print_notices(); ?>

<div class="woocommerce-box">

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form' ); ?>

<?php if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration' ) === 'yes' ) : ?>

<div class="u-columns col2-set" id="customer_login">

 <div class="u-column1 col-1">

<?php endif; ?>

  <h2><?php _e( 'Login', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

  <form method="post" class="login">

   <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_start' ); ?>

   <p class="woocommerce-FormRow woocommerce-FormRow--wide form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="username"><?php _e( 'Username or email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['username'] ); ?>" />
   </p>
   <p class="woocommerce-FormRow woocommerce-FormRow--wide form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="password"><?php _e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" type="password" name="password" id="password" />
   </p>

   <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form' ); ?>

   <p class="form-row">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-login', 'woocommerce-login-nonce' ); ?>
    <input type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="login" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Login', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
    <label for="rememberme" class="inline">
     <input class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--checkbox" name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" /> <?php _e( 'Remember me', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </label>
   </p>
   <p class="woocommerce-LostPassword lost_password">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_lostpassword_url() ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Lost your password?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
   </p>

   <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_end' ); ?>

  </form>

<?php if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration' ) === 'yes' ) : ?>

 </div>

 <div class="u-column2 col-2">

  <h2><?php _e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

  <form method="post" class="register">

   <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start' ); ?>

   <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username' ) ) : ?>

    <p class="woocommerce-FormRow woocommerce-FormRow--wide form-row form-row-wide">
     <label for="reg_username"><?php _e( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
     <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="reg_username" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['username'] ); ?>" />
    </p>

   <?php endif; ?>

   <p class="woocommerce-FormRow woocommerce-FormRow--wide form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="reg_email"><?php _e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['email'] ); ?>" />
   </p>

   <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ) : ?>

    <p class="woocommerce-FormRow woocommerce-FormRow--wide form-row form-row-wide">
     <label for="reg_password"><?php _e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
     <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" />
    </p>

   <?php endif; ?>

   <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form' ); ?>
   <?php do_action( 'register_form' ); ?>

   <p class="woocommerce-FormRow form-row">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce' ); ?>
    <input type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="register" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
   </p>

   <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_end' ); ?>

  </form>

 </div>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_customer_login_form' ); ?>

</div>
```

not able to register the user from My Account Page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be possible, this issue cause due to fields hidden in Custom CSS in Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS, check that might work.

Comment: thanx, yeah those were hidden